# Maximum Path Sum

Tags: java

I'm trying to develop a Java program to solve https://projecteuler.net/problem=18 . However I've run into difficulties and I'm not sure why this code doesn't work:

```
int[][] testTriangle = {
            {3},
            {7, 4},
            {2, 4, 6},
            {8, 5, 9, 3}
    };

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hasGoneDownRoute = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); //Stores numbers and start positions to numbers

    int largestValue = 0;
    int value = 0;
    int row = testTriangle.length-1;
    for (int startPosition = 0; startPosition <= testTriangle[row].length-1; startPosition++) { //starts from all possible start positions on the bottom row
        for (int y = 1; y<=2; y++) { //executes from the same start position twice to get all possible routes (ACTUALLY THIS MIGHT BE WRONG!?)
            while (row != 0) { //until it reaches the top row
                if (startPosition == 0) { //if it's on the far left
                    value += testTriangle[row-1][0];
                }
                else if (startPosition == testTriangle[row].length-1) { //if at's on the far right
                    value += testTriangle[row-1][testTriangle[row-1].length-1]; //set the value to the row above it on the far right
                }
                else { //This never gets called?
                    int noToChooseFrom1 = testTriangle[row-1][startPosition]; //above it and to the right
                    int noToChooseFrom2 = testTriangle[row-1][startPosition-1]; //above it and to the left
                    if (hasGoneDownRoute.containsKey(noToChooseFrom1) && hasGoneDownRoute.get(noToChooseFrom1) == startPosition) { //checks if it has gone down a certain route before
                        value += noToChooseFrom2;
                        hasGoneDownRoute.put(testTriangle[row-1][startPosition-1], startPosition);
                    }
                    else {
                        value += noToChooseFrom1;
                        hasGoneDownRoute.put(noToChooseFrom1, startPosition);
                    }
                }
                row--;
            }
        }
        if (value > largestValue) {
            largestValue = value;
        }
        System.out.println(largestValue);
    }
```

I just added notes to try and explain my thought process

Comment: What does it output?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just looked at this question And my programming skills are much better now. It may be a dead question but. Id rather give the correct answer.

What you really need is recursion. it allows you to look ahead in a way that the for loop will not. (Easily anyways)

Create a function

```
public int findLargestPath(int[][] triangle, row , col) {

    // Check to see if the row and column are actually in the triangle
    if(col == -1 || col >= triangle[row].length) 
    {
        return -1; //If they are not. ensure that this path wont be taken. 
    }
    if(row == triangle.length -1)
    {
        return triangle[row][col]; //Return the value.
    }
    else
    {
        //return this value plus the maximum path below
        return triangle[row][col]+Math.max(findLargestPath(row+1,col),
                                           findLargestPath(row+1,col+1));
    }
}
```

Then inside the main it would be a simple

```
int[][] testTriangle = {
        {3},
        {7, 4},
        {2, 4, 6},
        {8, 5, 9, 3}
};

System.out.println("The Maximum Path = "+findLargestPath(testTriangle,0,0));
```

The recursion is a way to keep track of all the routes without the need to create new variables. I don't have an IDE in-front of me. So there are probably a couple errors in there. If you want me to fix it. let me know and when a get back to an IDE ill test it all.

Answer (score 0):

https://projecteuler.net/problem=18

dynamic programming approach:

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tri[][] = {
        {
            6,
            0,
            0
        },
        {
            2,
            -3,
            0
        },
        {
            9,
            20,
            -1
        }
    };
    System.out.println(maxPathSum(tri)); 
}


static int maxPathSum(int tri[][]) {  
    for (int i = tri.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            //second condition in conditional ensures that we don't add 
            //negative numbers, which would only decrease our max sum
            if (tri[i][j] > tri[i][j + 1] && tri[i][j] + tri[i - 1][j] > tri[i - 1][j]) {
                tri[i - 1][j] += tri[i][j];
           } else if (tri[i][j] < tri[i][j + 1] && [i][j + 1] + tri[i - 1][j] > tri[i - 1][j]) {
                tri[i - 1][j] += tri[i][j + 1];
             }
        }
    }
    return tri[0][0];
}
```